# MySQL Performance Issue with Primary Key in ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I have huge performance problems with a MySQL query when using `ORDER BY`

The following query returns over 5M rows and executes very fast (<0,1s)

```
SELECT * FROM logins WHERE users_id = 1
```

As soon as I add `ORDER BY` the query slows down to over 30s

```
SELECT * FROM logins WHERE users_id = 1 ORDER BY id
```

`id` is `PRIMARY KEY` and `users_id` has an `INDEX`.

Since both `users_id` and `id` are indexed, I do not understand why the second query is taking so much longer.

When I run `EXPLAIN` the used `key` is always `users_id`.

How can I make the second query (much) faster?
Is MySQL only using that index and ignoring the primary key?
Should I use a compound index for `users_id` and `id`?

Comment: Try [8.9.3 Index Hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html).

Comment: plz share logins table structure and index details and count of table as well  count of user_id=1.

Comment: Pro tip: Avoid `SELECT *` in favor of giving the names of the columns you actually need. For example, `SELECT id, users_id, username`.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal index for this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM logins
WHERE users_id = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

Is `logins(users_id, id)`.  The `where` and `order by` could both take advantage of the existing indexes.   MySQL determines that the selectivity for the `where` is more important than the ordering by `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides alternative indexing, take a looke here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Especially at the end:

> To increase ORDER BY speed, check whether you can get MySQL to use indexes rather than an extra sorting phase. If this is not possible, you can try the following strategies:
>
> Increase the [sort_buffer_size variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) value.
>
> Increase the [read_rnd_buffer_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_rnd_buffer_size) variable value.
>
> Use less RAM per row by declaring columns only as large as they need to be to hold the values stored in them. For example, CHAR(16) is better than CHAR(200) if values never exceed 16 characters.
>
> Change the tmpdir system variable to point to a dedicated file system with large amounts of free space. The variable value can list several paths that are used in round-robin fashion; you can use this feature to spread the load across several directories. Paths should be separated by colon characters (“:”) on Unix and semicolon characters (“;”) on Windows, NetWare, and OS/2. The paths should name directories in file systems located on different physical disks, not different partitions on the same disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try an index with both (users_id,id) as fields. This will give MySQL the opportunity to use an index that can select the records already in the correct order.